# Custom Labels for Pie Charts in React

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to use the example seen here: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomActiveShapePieChart, but I want to have that label on every part of the chart rather than just the active part. I tried making it so that all states were active at the start, but on mouse enter, only one state remains active. How can I get the same label with the same style and path component for all the sectors? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just make activeIndex an array of indexes. For example in the recharts example `data.length` is 4, so activeIndex will be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. And remove the `onMouseEnter` attribute from Pie, so that on hover it does not activate only one label.

```
const TwoLevelPieChart = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      activeIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    };
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
        <Pie 
          activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
          activeShape={renderActiveShape} 
          data={data} 
          cx={300} 
          cy={200} 
          innerRadius={60}
          outerRadius={80} 
          fill="#8884d8"
        />
     </PieChart>
    );
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to install chart-js-plugin-datalabels

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save

import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

return
<Pie
      label={label}
      data={datas}
      options={{
        plugins: {
        // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
        datalabels: {
          formatter: function(value, context) {
            return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
        }
        }
       }
     }
    }
    />
```